# Problema al leer un .csv con líneas en blanco al final del archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con un archivo .csv con tres columnas de datos separados por ','. Copio dos de las tres columnas en dos listas para más adelante procesar la información. El copiado se realiza con éxito en todas las líneas pero al llegar al final del archivo tengo dos filas vacías que hacen que me salga un error por intentar asignar lo que hay en esas líneas (nada) a tres variables.

El código es el siguiente:

```
# Abrimos el archivo.
csvarchivo = open(direct)
# Leemos todos los registros.
data = csv.reader(csvarchivo)

# Creamos las listas en las que almacenar los datos de cada columna.
col_02 = []
col_03 = []

# Guardamos las columnas segunda y tercera en una lista cada una.
for row in data:
    # Leemos la fila row y guardamos cada elemento en una variable.
    element_01, element_02, element_03 = row
    # Asignamos cada variable a su lista.
    col_02.append(float(element_02))
    col_03.append(float(element_03))


# Cerramos el archivo.
data.close()
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que obvie las líneas en blanco y así evitar que me de error?

PD: Borrar las líneas a mano no es una opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando lees una línea vacía, la variable `row` también estará vacía. Puedes comprobar ese hecho y saltarte esa línea (`continue`).

Por otro lado, la última línea del código estaba mal, pues el fichero a cerrar es `csvarchivo` y no `data`.

```py
# Abrimos el archivo.
csvarchivo = open(direct)
# Leemos todos los registros.
data = csv.reader(csvarchivo)

# Creamos las listas en las que almacenar los datos de cada columna.
col_02 = []
col_03 = []

# Guardamos las columnas segunda y tercera en una lista cada una.
for row in data:
    if not row:
        continue
    # Leemos la fila row y guardamos cada elemento en una variable.
    element_01, element_02, element_03 = row
    # Asignamos cada variable a su lista.
    col_02.append(float(element_02))
    col_03.append(float(element_03))


print(col_02)
print(col_03)
# Cerramos el archivo.
csvarchivo.close()
```

Observa no obstante que puede seguir dándote errores si la fila que lees no tiene exactamente tres columnas. Puedes saltarte las líneas problemáticas así:

```py
for row in data:
    if len(row)!=3:
        continue
    # El resto igual...
```

**Actualización**. A petición del usuario, explico un poco la lógica del:

```py
if not row:
   continue
```

Para python algunos tipos de datos evaluados en un contexto de expresión booleana, tienen un "valor de verdad". En el caso anterior, `row` es en realidad una lista, pero ya que la evaluamos en el contexto de una expresión booleana (en un `if`) Python usará su "valor de verdad".

El valor de verdad de una lista es `True` si la lista tiene elementos, o `False` si no tiene ninguno.

Por tanto `not row` dará `True` si la fila en cuestión es una lista vacía, que es lo que ocurre cuando el CSV tenía una línea en blanco. En ese caso se ejecutará el cuerpo del `if`, que dice `continue`.

La operación `continue` significa: "abandona el todo lo que queda por hacer en esta iteración del bucle y pasa a la siguiente iteración".

El `else` no es necesario, ya que si la condición no se cumple (porque `row` tiene elementos), simplemente el `continue` no será ejecutado, y por tanto seguiremos ejecutando lo que va después del `if`.

Otra forma de hacer lo mismo, pero que he preferido no usar porque incrementa la indentación un nivel más, sería:

```py
for row in data:
    if row:
       # Código para procesar la fila
       # element_01 ...
       # col_02.append...
       # col_03.append...
```

En este caso `if row` se lee como "si hay datos en la fila", y entonces la procesa, mientras que si no los hay el cuerpo del `if` no se ejecutará y pasaremos a la siguiente iteración del bucle.

Comment: No comprendo la sintaxis `if not row` aunque entiendo lo que hace. ¿Puedes explicarla?

Comment: ¿No es necesario añadir un `else`?

Comment: @Zhisi He añadido una explicación