# Cargar un diccionario utilizando una lista - TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, array

Muy buenas noches. Les cuento. Tengo un archivo llamado cotizacion.csv, el cual contiene las cotizaciones de las empresas del IBEX35 con las siguientes columnas: Nombre, Final, Máximo, Mínimo, Volumen, Efectivo.
La información contenida en este archivo la cargo en una variable de manera que me quede una lista de listas como esta:

```
aux = [['Nombre', 'Final', 'Máximo', 'Mínimo', 'Volumen', 'Efectivo'], 
       ['ACCIONA', '95,95', '96,75', '94,4', '84.962', '8166,11'], 
       ['ACERINOX', '8668', '8672', '8468', '885.99', '7633,81'], 
       ['ACS', '37,28', '37,66', '37,22', '655.982', '24517,29'], 
       ['AENA', '167,1', '167,5', '166,1', '133.738', '22336,10'], 
       ['AMADEUS', '69,96', '70,64', '69,56', '640.476', '44795,47'], 
       ['ARCELORMIT.', '14152', '14318', '14,08', '702.841', '9989,65'], 
       ['BA.SABADELL', '1,0165', '1033', '1,0165', '12.358.512', '12637,65'], 
       ['BA.SANTANDER', '4,02', '4,0675', '4,01', '36.129.692', '145765,44'], 
       ['BANKIA', '2249', '2262', '2224', '3.024.454', '6803,54'], 
       ['BANKINTER', '6,56', '6604', '6522', '1.375.976', '9030,20'], 
       ['BBVA', '5024', '5,05', '4969', '26.447.612', '132560,15'], 
       ['CAIXABANK', '2763', '2806', '2762', '13.031.097', '36239,22'], 
       ['CELLNEX', '30,17', '30,7', '30,17', '857.237', '25965,29'], 
       ['CIE AUTOMOT.', '23,44', '23,74', '23,4', '99.506', '2343,09'], 
       ['ENAGAS', '25,6', '25,66', '25,07', '842.54', '21524,77'], 
       ['ENCE', '3882', '3974', '3846', '2.099.698', '8219,83'], 
       ['ENDESA', '22,95', '23,03', '22,62', '1.236.799', '28233,46'], 
       ['FERROVIAL', '21,61', '21,72', '21,38', '2.065.931', '44656,05'], 
       ['GRIFOLS CL.A', '23,3', '23,6', '23,27', '719.503', '16787,55'], 
       ['IAG', '5,3', '5,46', '5292', '2.155.081', '11561,95'], 
       ['IBERDROLA', '8,45', '8,45', '8262', '15.637.958', '131426,05'], 
       ['INDITEX', '24,93', '25,19', '24,87', '2.600.144', '65012,92'], 
       ['INDRA A', '9,56', '9685', '9535', '392.06', '3755,57'], 
       ['INM.COLONIAL', '9915', '9915', '9745', '671.753', '6640,38'], 
       ['MAPFRE', '2654', '2654', '2,62', '3.045.972', '8063,13'], 
       ['MEDIASET', '6446', '6592', '6446', '2.647.557', '17277,04'], 
       ['MELIA HOTELS', '8,14', '8,19', '8,02', '480.21', '3914,93'], 
       ['MERLIN', '12,08', '12,08', '11,83', '777.543', '9357,77'], 
       ['NATURGY', '26,7', '26,77', '26,53', '2.100.737', '55986,54'], 
       ['R.E.C.', '19705', '19875', '19675', '1.246.171', '24585,33'], 
       ['REPSOL', '14515', '14605', '14,46', '5.046.648', '73333,78'], 
       ['SIEMENS GAME', '14,33', '14,39', '14155', '1.054.847', '15084,56'], 
       ['TEC.REUNIDAS', '23', '23,2', '22,78', '122.1', '2807,19'], 
       ['TELEFONICA', '7204', '7256', '7185', '9.913.249', '71564,99'], 
       ['VISCOFAN', '48,46', '49,12', '48,46', '67.71', '3295,43'], ['']]
```

Ahora, lo que se me pide es crear un diccionario para cada una de las columnas de la forma:

```
Columna = {'Empresa1' : 'valor1', 'Empresa2': 'valor2'...'Empresa(n)': 'valor(n)}
```

Para lograr aquello ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
Final = {} 
Max = {} 
Min = {} 
Vol = {} 
Efectivo = {}

j = 1
while j < 6:
    k = 1
    while k < 36:
        if aux[k] is not None:
            aux[0][j][aux[k][0]] = aux[k][j]
            k = k + 1
        else:
            break
    j = j + 1
```

Lo cual me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto debido a que esta línea de código:

```
aux[0][j][aux[k][0]] = aux[k][j]
```

En vez de verse así:

```
Final['ACCIONA'] = '95,95'
```

Se está viendo así:

```
'Final'['ACCIONA'] = '95,95'
```

Entonces mi pregunta es... ¡¿COMO LO ARREGLO?! jaja, ya no se me ocurrió a mí, no hay caso. Desde ya muchas gracias!

PD: sin "pandas"

Comment: gero, si editas la pregunta y añades la lista de datos (en vez de una imagen) creo que podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ahí agregue los datos!

Comment: También deberías incluir el error como texto.

Comment: Pregunta: El resultado debe ser: `{"name_empresa":{"final":94,...}...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acabo de ver por la respuesta de CandidMoe que querías todas las columnas, no solo la primera.

Creo que lo más oportuno para eso es un diccionario que tenga dentro los diccionarios que pides, con la siguiente estructura:

```
cotizaciones = {'Final': {'ACCIONA': '95.95', 
                          'ACERINOX': '8668', 
                          'ACS': '37.28', 
                           ...},
                'Máximo': {'ACCIONA': '96.75', 
                           'ACERINOX': '8672', 
                           'ACS': '37.66', 
                            ...},
                'Mínimo': {'ACCIONA': '94.4', 
                           'ACERINOX': '8468', 
                           'ACS': '37.22', 
                            ...},
                'Volumen': {'ACCIONA': '84.962', 
                            'ACERINOX': '885.99', 
                            'ACS': '655.982', 
                             ...},
                'Efectivo': {'ACCIONA': '8166.11', 
                             'ACERINOX': '7633.81', 
                             'ACS': '24517.29', 
                              ...}}
```

Ya que luego podrás acceder a los datos facilmente, por ejemplo con `cotizaciones['Final']` accederías a `{'ACCIONA': '95.95', 'ACERINOX': '8668', 'ACS': '37.28', ...}`

Para ello puedes hacerlo así partiendo de tus datos:

```
cotizaciones = {}
for i, titulo in enumerate(aux[0][1:], 1):
    cotizaciones[titulo] = {fila[0]: fila[i] for fila in aux[1:]}
print(cotizaciones)
```

Eso si, para esto tendrías que arreglar antes la parte en la que tu código te lee el csv, ya que te está incluyendo la ultima línea en blanco que tiene el archivo:

```
..., '3295,43'], ['']]
```

Esto `['']` es porque está leyendo una línea vacía al final. Puede que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160920/problema-al-leer-un-csv-con-l%C3%ADneas-en-blanco-al-final-del-archivo) pregunta te ayude a solucionarlo.

**Posible mejora**

No sé exactamente cómo importas los datos, pero si no necesitas el resto de valores, es decir, que la variable `aux` la has creado como un paso intermedio para conseguir el diccionario (su nombre hace pensar eso), puedes crearlo directamente al leer el archivo.

```
import csv

archivo = '<ruta de tu archivo>/archivo.csv'

with open(archivo, 'r') as datos:

    reader = csv.DictReader(datos)
    cotizaciones = {titulo: {} for titulo in reader.fieldnames[1:]}
    for row in reader:
        for titulo in cotizaciones:
            cotizaciones[titulo][row['Nombre']] = row[titulo]

print(cotizaciones)
```

Dependiendo de la forma en la que esté este escrito tu csv esto te lo puede hacer directamente, y si no te funciona, publica dos o tres lineas de tu csv porque los cambios que hay que hacer serían mínimos.

Comment: si en : dic = {l[0]:l[1] for l in aux[1:]} estás omitiendo el índice 0 , ¿por qué  no omitir el último? = dic = {l[0]:l[1] for l in aux[1:-1]} y no tendría que arreglar la lista

Comment: @tincopasan, también en este caso se podría hacer (de hecho pensé en ponerlo), pero porque sabes que solamente hay una línea vacía al final, pero qué pasa si hay lineas intermedias vacías? en este caso con [1:] quitas el encabezado porque es si que estará arriba del todo y lo normal es que sea una línea. De ser dos o más con poner [2:] o lo que corresponda también valdría.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 3):

Solución: una lista conteniendo una diccionario por columna

```
columna = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]

for empresa in aux[1:-1]:
    for i in range(1, len(empresa)):
        columna[i - 1][empresa[0]] = empresa[i]
```

El primero `for` recorre las empresas, saltandose el primer y último elemento de la lista (header y lista vacia).

Por cada empresa, recorremos sus campos y vamos incorporandolos al respectivo diccionario.

**Demo**

```
columna = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]

for empresa in aux[1:-1]:
    for i in range(1, len(empresa)):
        columna[i - 1][empresa[0]] = empresa[i]

for i in columna:
    print(i)
```

produce:

```
{'ACCIONA': '95,95', 'ACERINOX': '8668', 'ACS': '37,28', 'AENA': '167,1', 'AMADEUS': '69,96', 'ARCELORMIT.': '14152', 'BA.SABADELL': '1,0165', 'BA.SANTANDER': '4,02', 'BANKIA': '2249', 'BANKINTER': '6,56', 'BBVA': '5024', 'CAIXABANK': '2763', 'CELLNEX': '30,17', 'CIE AUTOMOT.': '23,44', 'ENAGAS': '25,6', 'ENCE': '3882', 'ENDESA': '22,95', 'FERROVIAL': '21,61', 'GRIFOLS CL.A': '23,3', 'IAG': '5,3', 'IBERDROLA': '8,45', 'INDITEX': '24,93', 'INDRA A': '9,56', 'INM.COLONIAL': '9915', 'MAPFRE': '2654', 'MEDIASET': '6446', 'MELIA HOTELS': '8,14', 'MERLIN': '12,08', 'NATURGY': '26,7', 'R.E.C.': '19705', 'REPSOL': '14515', 'SIEMENS GAME': '14,33', 'TEC.REUNIDAS': '23', 'TELEFONICA': '7204', 'VISCOFAN': '48,46'}
{'ACCIONA': '96,75', 'ACERINOX': '8672', 'ACS': '37,66', 'AENA': '167,5', 'AMADEUS': '70,64', 'ARCELORMIT.': '14318', 'BA.SABADELL': '1033', 'BA.SANTANDER': '4,0675', 'BANKIA': '2262', 'BANKINTER': '6604', 'BBVA': '5,05', 'CAIXABANK': '2806', 'CELLNEX': '30,7', 'CIE AUTOMOT.': '23,74', 'ENAGAS': '25,66', 'ENCE': '3974', 'ENDESA': '23,03', 'FERROVIAL': '21,72', 'GRIFOLS CL.A': '23,6', 'IAG': '5,46', 'IBERDROLA': '8,45', 'INDITEX': '25,19', 'INDRA A': '9685', 'INM.COLONIAL': '9915', 'MAPFRE': '2654', 'MEDIASET': '6592', 'MELIA HOTELS': '8,19', 'MERLIN': '12,08', 'NATURGY': '26,77', 'R.E.C.': '19875', 'REPSOL': '14605', 'SIEMENS GAME': '14,39', 'TEC.REUNIDAS': '23,2', 'TELEFONICA': '7256', 'VISCOFAN': '49,12'}
{'ACCIONA': '94,4', 'ACERINOX': '8468', 'ACS': '37,22', 'AENA': '166,1', 'AMADEUS': '69,56', 'ARCELORMIT.': '14,08', 'BA.SABADELL': '1,0165', 'BA.SANTANDER': '4,01', 'BANKIA': '2224', 'BANKINTER': '6522', 'BBVA': '4969', 'CAIXABANK': '2762', 'CELLNEX': '30,17', 'CIE AUTOMOT.': '23,4', 'ENAGAS': '25,07', 'ENCE': '3846', 'ENDESA': '22,62', 'FERROVIAL': '21,38', 'GRIFOLS CL.A': '23,27', 'IAG': '5292', 'IBERDROLA': '8262', 'INDITEX': '24,87', 'INDRA A': '9535', 'INM.COLONIAL': '9745', 'MAPFRE': '2,62', 'MEDIASET': '6446', 'MELIA HOTELS': '8,02', 'MERLIN': '11,83', 'NATURGY': '26,53', 'R.E.C.': '19675', 'REPSOL': '14,46', 'SIEMENS GAME': '14155', 'TEC.REUNIDAS': '22,78', 'TELEFONICA': '7185', 'VISCOFAN': '48,46'}
{'ACCIONA': '84.962', 'ACERINOX': '885.99', 'ACS': '655.982', 'AENA': '133.738', 'AMADEUS': '640.476', 'ARCELORMIT.': '702.841', 'BA.SABADELL': '12.358.512', 'BA.SANTANDER': '36.129.692', 'BANKIA': '3.024.454', 'BANKINTER': '1.375.976', 'BBVA': '26.447.612', 'CAIXABANK': '13.031.097', 'CELLNEX': '857.237', 'CIE AUTOMOT.': '99.506', 'ENAGAS': '842.54', 'ENCE': '2.099.698', 'ENDESA': '1.236.799', 'FERROVIAL': '2.065.931', 'GRIFOLS CL.A': '719.503', 'IAG': '2.155.081', 'IBERDROLA': '15.637.958', 'INDITEX': '2.600.144', 'INDRA A': '392.06', 'INM.COLONIAL': '671.753', 'MAPFRE': '3.045.972', 'MEDIASET': '2.647.557', 'MELIA HOTELS': '480.21', 'MERLIN': '777.543', 'NATURGY': '2.100.737', 'R.E.C.': '1.246.171', 'REPSOL': '5.046.648', 'SIEMENS GAME': '1.054.847', 'TEC.REUNIDAS': '122.1', 'TELEFONICA': '9.913.249', 'VISCOFAN': '67.71'}
{'ACCIONA': '8166,11', 'ACERINOX': '7633,81', 'ACS': '24517,29', 'AENA': '22336,10', 'AMADEUS': '44795,47', 'ARCELORMIT.': '9989,65', 'BA.SABADELL': '12637,65', 'BA.SANTANDER': '145765,44', 'BANKIA': '6803,54', 'BANKINTER': '9030,20', 'BBVA': '132560,15', 'CAIXABANK': '36239,22', 'CELLNEX': '25965,29', 'CIE AUTOMOT.': '2343,09', 'ENAGAS': '21524,77', 'ENCE': '8219,83', 'ENDESA': '28233,46', 'FERROVIAL': '44656,05', 'GRIFOLS CL.A': '16787,55', 'IAG': '11561,95', 'IBERDROLA': '131426,05', 'INDITEX': '65012,92', 'INDRA A': '3755,57', 'INM.COLONIAL': '6640,38', 'MAPFRE': '8063,13', 'MEDIASET': '17277,04', 'MELIA HOTELS': '3914,93', 'MERLIN': '9357,77', 'NATURGY': '55986,54', 'R.E.C.': '24585,33', 'REPSOL': '73333,78', 'SIEMENS GAME': '15084,56', 'TEC.REUNIDAS': '2807,19', 'TELEFONICA': '71564,99', 'VISCOFAN': '3295,43'}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que la mejor manera de organizar esos datos es guardarlos en una Lista de diccionarios/json

```py
final = {}
maximo = {}
minimo = {}
for dato in aux[1:]:
    if len(dato)>1:
        final[dato[0]] = dato[1]
        maximo[dato[0]] = dato[2]
        minimo[dato[0]] = dato[3]     
print(final["ACCIONA"])
```

Resultado:

```
'95,95'
```

Comment: Yo también habría propuesto una estructura de datos diferente, pero y esto `Columna = {'Empresa' : 'valor'}`?

Comment: Sería un diccionario en el que las claves son los nombres de las distintas empresas y los valores las cifras cotizadas

Comment: Gero, te refieres a algo asi?? nuevos_datos["ACCIONA"]["final"] = 7204

Comment: La idea es, obtener un diccionario cuyo nombre sea el de una de las columnas, por ejemplo "Final" y cuyas claves y valores sean los respectivos nombres de las empresas y sus cotizaciones

Comment: Ahí edite la parte en la que describo el resultado buscado. Muchas gracias igual!!

Comment: Entiendo. Para cada columna quieres un diccionario diferente y apuntar al valor usando el nombre de la empresa. Ahi edite el código

Comment: @Christian Hola, ignore esa parte porque creo que la estructura de lista y diccionario es lo correcto. Igual forma edite el código para que OP pudiera acceder a los datos como el quiere (según entiendo)

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre usar un bucle `for` para cargar el diccionario:

```python
salida={i:[] for i in aux[0]};#Rellenamos nuestro diccionario.
```

Despues anidamos dos bucles. Para rellenar nuestra lista vacia:

```python
salida={i:[] for i in aux[0]};

for y in range(1,len(aux)):#La pocision y.
    x=0;#La posicion x.
    lenght=len(aux[y]);#Por seguridad
    for name in salida:#Los key de las filas.
        if lenght>x:#Para que no ocurra excepciones. Por si hay menos filas que los nombres de las colunnas.
            salida[name].append(aux[y][x]);#Obtenemos el key actual y colocamos la aux[y][x] dentro de su lista.
            x+=1;#x++; Recorremos a otra posicion.


print(salida);#Listo
```

Explicación paso a paso:

Lo que hice fue usar un diccionario con una lista vacía como valor:

`salida={"key":[]}`

La clave la obtuve con la primera columna de la lista `aux`:

```
salida={};
for i in aux[0]:
    salida.setdefault(i,[]);
```

Ya obtenidos los índices y su correspondiente lista lo que después hice fue agarrar uno a uno las columnas de la lista `aux`:

```
for y in range(1,len(aux)):  # 1 porque no nos interesa esa colunna.
```

Inicio la posición `x` para después aumentarla con otro bucle `for` y así recorrer la parte que necesito de la lista `x=0`

Después inicio la variable `lenght` que nos dirá los limite de la lista:

```
lenght=len(aux[y])
```

Después hice otro bucle `for` para obtener las palabras clave del diccionario:

```
for name in salida:
```

Después le agregué el `if` para seguridad y que no ocurran excepciones:

```
if lenght>x:
```

Después agarre el índice del diccionario y use la función `append` para agrandar la lista y colocar el valor deseado a cada una:

```
salida[name].append(aux[y][x])
```

Al final aumenté el indice `x+=1`

[Más lectura](https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-list-python/)

Comment: ¿Cual es la idea de ocultar el texto?

Comment: @CandidMoe Queria darle la opcion de leer solo la parte mas importante y si el lector queria ver la expricacion paso a paso, tambien queria ver como esta pagina ocultaba el texto.

Comment: La ocultación impide leer fluidamente la respuesta.